# Vertically center div in a div with height auto

Tags: vertical-alignment, centering, css

Well, I got this structure:

```css
    
    #parent{
       max-width: 800px;
       height: auto;
       margin: auto;
    }
    #child{
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 52px;
       display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
       <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
```

The child div is hidden per default. It gets visible by using jQuery (.fadeIn). Now the question is, how can I vertically center the child element by using only css?

Comment: In this case, parent div will have height of child div, so centering doesn't have too much sense?

Comment: Why only using CSS when you use `fadeIn()` with jQuery? So you already are dependent on JavaScript

Comment: However, great link: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a prototype... But I had to modify your HTML and CSS so it might not be the best solution: http://jsfiddle.net/TmCwB/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="parent">
         <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outerDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
#parent{   
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}
#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

```
#child{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 52px;
    /*display:none;*/
   display: block;
   background-color: blue;
   top:50%;
}
```

just add **top:50%** to your CSS code.

http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/dry2Q/

Comment: Won't work properly 'cause the child div will get positioned 50% from the top even when it has a height of 300px... So position is absolute and not centered.

Comment: If the height of your child is known this can still work by setting the `margin-top` to negative half the child's height.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Thank you for your answers. Atrox11's answer was the right one but I found out that there was another issue that I had to deal with.

There's another wraper div. Since all my children divs are positioned absolute, the parent div had a height of 0px. This was the actual fault. After I fixed that, everything worked as expected.

Sorry for the question. I would appreciate it, if you won't rate it down, since everyone makes some mistakes when he is in a hurry.