# how could I realize css vertical and horizontal centering?

Tags: css, layout

How could I vertically center a child  within a parent  ?

And, the width and height of child  and parent  is fixed, but unknown.

How could I realize it?

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically center div in a div with height auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326981/vertically-center-div-in-a-div-with-height-auto)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prefered technique for centering a box both vertically and horizontally requires two containers.

---

### The outher container

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box

- should have `display: inline-block;`
- should re-adjust the horizontal text-alignment to eg. `text-align: left;` or `text-align: right;`, unless you want text to be centered

The elegance of this technique, is that **you can add your content to the content box without worrying about its height or width!**

Just add your content to the content box.

### Demo

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* This could be ANY width */
    height: 100%; /* This could be ANY height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        <p>You can put anything here</p>
        <p>Yes, really anything!</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/621/)!

Answer (score 1):

in css `vertical-align:middle` is used to align a child vertically centre. But this property is applied to only those elements which have`display:inline-block` or `display:table-cell`. So accordingly try to apply `display` property and you will get vertically centre position of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can center things through:
    margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.div1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.div2 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #999;
}
```